# Playing videos over local network on an iPad

Tags: html, ipad, video, local, simplehttpserver

I have a website that I have made on my desktop, and I am viewing it on my iPad. I am doing this by accessing 'computername.local:8000' after sharing the folder using

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Everything works fine, apart from videos, they just show up with the cross through the play icon.

This is the code I am using for the video:

```
<video id="thevideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" 
controls preload="auto" poster="poster.jpg" data-setup="{}"> 

<source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4'></video>
```

Is there any way to make the video play via this method? Or is there an alternative way of sharing a folder locally with an iPad?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen the `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` trick before. But I tried it out and was able to get it to serve some static files. However, as soon as I tried to serve a large .MP4 file in support of a video tag, I saw this output (and the server kept running):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Did you see that? This is Python 2.7.3 on Linux; it looks like you're on Mac OS X so it might look a little different.

Anyway, I got that same broken playback icon on the iPad that you saw. I'm guessing that the simple Python HTTP server just doesn't know how to serve that much data at once.

Alternative solution: If all you need right now is a simple, static, barebones HTTP server, I recommend [webfs](http://linux.bytesex.org/misc/webfs.html). Compile it into a command line and execute it from anywhere to establish an unprivileged static HTTP server on port 8000 (by default). I just tested it out and was able to stream a basic .MP4 file to the iPad via the video tag in Safari.